# Way to reset location warnings in iOS6?

Tags: ios, web-applications, safari, geolocation, ios6

In iOS 5 to reset location warnings you could do the following:

`Settings.app -> General -> Reset -> Reset Location Warnings`

This doesn't exist as far as I can tell in iOS 6. Need to get past the 'asking three times and then not asking anymore' prompt in a web app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try...
Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy